# Failed to get response on runtime

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net

I make a web form having a table in which one column getting values from the database and other column contains button for every record.

```
<table style="width: 44%;">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <b>User Name</b>
            </td>
            <td>
                <b>Approval</b>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <% for (i = 0; i < admin_dd.Rows.Count; i++)
           {%>
        <tr id="raw_<%=i %>">
            <td>
                <%=admin_dd.Rows[i][0]%>
            </td>
            <td>
                <% pos = Int32.Parse(admin_dd.Rows[i][1].ToString());

                %>
                <input type="button" onclick="" value="button" onclick="approve_func(pos)"/>

            </td>
        </tr>
        <% } %>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

What I want here, I want to send the value of "pos" to the button handler method and making changes into database , but i am failed to do so

```
protected void approve_func(int id)
    {

           DatabseClass.SetData("update tblUser SET Status=1 where ID=" + id);
           Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl);

      }
```

kindly help me resolving this issue.

Comment: Are you getting any exception?

Comment: If asp.net has something called grid then why this messy coding?

Comment: not getting any exception ,but database is not updating too .

Comment: Why `onclick` two times on anchor and c# code will not be called here because anchor is not server control

Comment: @Imad i am using table just because i wanted to add column at runtime.

Comment: Because you're not doing any postback here, you're calling a c# method from javascript. See your console, there will be a lot of errors.

Comment: @shifafatima you are adding row dynamically not columns and it can be done by gridview and quite easily

Comment: @Imad so how can i send pos value to my function ?

Comment: @shifafatima with this approach you will have to use ajax to send data to server

Comment: is not there other way witout using ajax ?

Comment: that's why I recommended grid.

Comment: @Shaharyar i am not getting any error but this code is not making any change when i am clicking on the button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to declare your method as a `WebMethod` in c#:

```
public static void approve_func(int id)
{
    DatabseClass.SetData("update tblUser SET Status=1 where ID=" + id);
}
```

and make an ajax call from the client side:

```
function update(id) {     
         $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: 'yourpagename.aspx/approve_func',     //add your page name
         data: "{id:id}",
         contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
         dataType: "json",
         success: function () {
            alert('success');
         },
         error: function (e) {
            alert('an error occurred');
         }
     });
 }
```

But I would recommend you to use `Gridview` instead of this messy approach. You can simply google **how to use gridview** and you'll get plenty of useful links.

Comment: @shifafatima You can accept it as answer if it helped you. Also it will tell other viewers of the question that it has been answered.

Comment: yeah it solved my issue but i had to make a tiny change.